# How can variational inference (for LDA) be explained in layman's terms?

Tags: topic-models, variational-bayes

I am learning probabilistic topic modeling, and I am studying latent Dirichlet allocation, specifically the inference process. I found many mathematical details, but I need a layman's explanation and/or an example of variational inference. I need something easy enough for a non mathematician.

Comment: Which meaning for LDA are you referring to? There are several.

Comment: I guess latent dirichlet allocation. See http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v3/blei03a.html

Comment: I think you need to split the problem up into: a) understanding the LDA model; b) understanding variational inference. If you start off not comfortable with either and try both at once, it will be extra confusing.